# Does @Everyone actually do something?

Tags: support, notifications

I saw someone use @Everyone in a comment recently - does that actually do something, and if so what are the semantics?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's either used to indicate that the comment is directed to everyone or used thinking that it notifies all the participants.

In practice, AFAIK, it doesn't notify anyone but the post's owner, the same that happens without it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you can only notify (leave a message in someone's inbox) one person in addition to the post owner. Additional @names don't get notified.